# Display the latest records from the right table and if records not available then at least show the records from left table

Tags: php, mysql

I have two table

1. tbl_register
2. tbl_societymyprofile

What I am doing is, I have to display the records from the `tbl_register` table and  I have to display the latest record from the `tbl_societymyprofile` table.

I have a tried the below query.

```
SELECT *
FROM   tbl_register AS r
       LEFT JOIN tbl_societymyprofile AS m
              ON r.reg_id = m.reg_id
WHERE  r.reg_id =(SELECT Max(secretary_id) AS c_id
                   FROM   tbl_societymyprofile
                   WHERE  reg_id = 17
                   GROUP  BY reg_id DESC)
       AND r.is_active = 1
```

Also if the records are not available in the `tbl_societymyprofile` then at least display the records from the `tbl_register` table.

`reg_id` id is the primary id of the `tbl_register` table. As of now I have the records in the `tbl_register` table but don't have the records in the `tbl_societymyprofile` and i am getting the empty records

**tbl_register**

```
reg_id | name | mobileno  | email     
1      | abc  |1234123455 |  abc@gmail.com
2      | xyz  |1234345455 |  xyz@gmail.com
```

**tbl_societymyprofile**

```
secretary_id | reg_id | sec_name | sec_email     | date_of_added
1            | 1      | ncx      | ncx@gmail.com | 2021-06-09 15:54:35
2            | 1      | xbs      | ncx@gmail.com | 2021-06-09 15:55:18
```

would you help me out with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need all records, try the following query:

```
SELECT r.*, 
       X.*
     FROM tbl_register AS r
LEFT JOIN (SELECT sp.* 
                 FROM tbl_societymyprofile sp
           INNER JOIN (SELECT reg_id, 
                              MAX(secretary_id) secretary_id
                       FROM tbl_societymyprofile
                       GROUP BY reg_id )T 
                   ON sp.reg_id = T.reg_id 
                  AND sp.secretary_id = T.secretary_id) X 
       ON r.reg_id = X.reg_id
```

If you need specific records, try the following query instead:

```
SELECT r.*, 
       X.*
FROM      tbl_register AS r
LEFT JOIN (SELECT sp.* 
             FROM     tbl_societymyprofile sp
           INNER JOIN (SELECT reg_id, 
                              MAX(secretary_id) secretary_id
                       FROM tbl_societymyprofile
                       GROUP BY reg_id           )T 
                   ON sp.reg_id = T.reg_id 
                  AND sp.secretary_id = T.secretary_id) X 
       ON r.reg_id = X.reg_id
WHERE r.reg_id = 2
```

Comment: Give me sometime to check.

Comment: which database and which version are you using. Although this query should work on all databases. use X.* and then check. May be case issue on your database.

Comment: X was in a small case.. Now I added in caps and getting some output.  I need to know where should I add the where condition to get the single record of the user

Comment: For example,I have to use the reg_id 2 from the register table to get the output

Comment: Give me sometime to check the answer

Comment: Yes, It's working. thank you so much for the help. Upvote from my side.

Answer (score 1):

If your joined table order is not important *(it usually isn't important)* then maybe you should try something like:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_register t LEFT JOIN tbl_societymyprofile s USING(reg_id) WHERE t.reg_id=2 ORDER BY s.date_of_adder DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Here's a [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5HFodZB6rL4wh5ZvajvJUv/0). See `Query #3`.

Comment: WOW. Simple and easy. Yes, it's working. upvote from my side.

Comment: which database are you using? Is it mysql ? Is "USING(reg_id)" equivalent to ON Table1.reg_id = Table2.reg_id ?